# Docx date properties not formatted like system dates

Tags: format, date, docx, properties

I have set the Windows 10 short date format to yyyy.MM.dd (in Control Panel Region settings), but when I look at a docx file's Properties from within Word 2016, I see dates formatted as dd/MM/yyyy. This is confusing. Can I change it?